# Find substring that have the the correlation greater than k in R

Tags: r, dataframe, substring, correlation

I have a big problems in R :(. We have a dataframe named:"hcmut" show the answers of students in half term test like here:

hcmut

Code  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |   5 |    6  |   7 |    8  |    9  |    10

2011  |  B  |  D  |  A  |  A  |   C |    B  |   A |    B  |    C  |     C

2012  |  A  |  D  | AC  |  B  |   D |    B  |   A |    B  |    C  |     C

2013  |  A  |  D  |  A  |  A  |   C |    D  |   C |    B  |    D  |     D

2014  |  A  |  B  |  A  |  C  |  BC |    D  |   D |    D  |    D  |     D

Question 1: find substring that have the corrrelation greater than k?

I think k is from range 0:1

Question 2: find substring that have the greatest correlation and show substring ( like "ABCD"...)

Could you help me with problem in R ?
:( :(

Comment: The question doesn't include any attempt to solve the problem. [Try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please show what you've tried and any specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). For more information [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).